# MVC3: Is it possible to change the result type outside of the code of the action itself?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, custom-attributes, action-filter

If I create an controller method that returns ActionResult, then call View() at the end, is there any way to have a Filter (or something simular) change the returned result from the ViewResult emitted by View() to a PartialViewResult based on conditions in the Request?

Clearly I can have code in the controller method itself that returns the ViewResult or PartialViewResult, but this comes up in a number of places so it seems like a good use of a Filter.  I tried doing this in both methods of the IResultFilter and saw no change in the output.

If this is not possible then I will look at creating some methods in my base controller called something like ViewOrPartial that I can call instead of View, but I wanted to seek broader wisdom before giving up on the Filter (or something like it) approach.

Thanks,
Matthew

Update: So it appears that at least one difference between what I had tried and what is now working based on Darin's code is that I had overridden OnResultExecuting (and I had also tried OnResultExecuted) and Darin's code overrides OnActionExecuted.  Does that seem odd or am I perhaps overlooking something else?  I am delighted to have it working but it seemed to make more sense that to attach it to the IResultFilter interface.  I will have to look into the intention of the two interfaces more.

Comment: I'm starting to use MVC3 and would really be interested in the answer!  I hope someone is able to provide a solution.

Comment: You absolutely can use an `IActionFilter` or `IResultFilter` to change the result. Did you remember to apply it? Can you post the code that's not working?

Comment: Stupidly I deleted it.  I have it working from Darin's code now but I am annoyed with myself that I won't know what I did wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

```
public class MyActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var result = filterContext.Result;
        var viewResult = result as ViewResult;
        var someValue = filterContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("someValue");
        if (viewResult != null && someValue != null && someValue.AttemptedValue == "foo")
        {
            // if the controller action returned a view result
            // and the someValue parameter equals foo we replace the 
            // view result initially returned by the action by a 
            // partial view result
            var partialResult = new PartialViewResult();
            partialResult.ViewData.Model = viewResult.Model;
            filterContext.Result = partialResult;
        }
    }
}
```

Then decorate:

```
[MyActionFilter]
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    MyViewModel vm = ...
    return View(vm);
}
```

Comment: +1, @Darin, how do you feel about putting this in an `ActionFilter` vs a custom derivative of `ViewResultBase`?

Comment: @smartcaveman, I do not have sufficient context to say definitely but a custom action result seems like a good idea. Of course without more enough context from the OP it is difficult to say. There might even be better solutions. That's the problem with most of the questions on SO. OPs simply do not explain sufficiently their scenarios and goals and by not doing this they might be missing even better answers which would be more adapted to their specific cases. The OP talked only that he wants to change the result from an action but in what purpose it is not clear.

Comment: Happy to provide more context. In order to do my app in a "progressive enhancement" way I have many of the actions return full pages by default but will render them in jquery ui dialogs if javascript is enabled.  In that case I don't need a full html page, just the snippet. I will endeavor to provide more context in the future.
Darin's code worked, and mine was pretty similar (I used a ResultFilter instead). I stupidly deleted it before I posted a question so I will not be a say for sure what I did wrong at this point.

Comment: This is great.  We frequently have forms where the initial view is complete (including master layouts) and filtering really is just a post back to the same initial action but is done with Ajax and only requires a partial result.  We did have an extension, ViewOrPartial, but this is much cleaner.  Our 'someValue' in your example is simply IsAjaxRequest() (from the Request object).  Thanks!